# Declare cursor as Variable or not

Tags: sql-server, syntax, scope, cursor, declaration

Sometimes I see SQL Server's cursor declaration as [variable](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/01/01/sql-server-simple-example-of-cursor/) and sometimes [not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

```
DECLARE @getAccountID CURSOR

DECLARE vend_cursor CURSOR
```

What is the significance and difference between the two manner of declaration ? Perhaps scope ?

Comment: It is. I did not find it on Google. Thanks @JamesZ

Comment: There is no significance.  It is an identifier.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223962(v=sql.80).aspx  I would add that most people do not use @ for cursor names as they typically reserve the @ for variable names.